# Where do Postgres DBLink queries run?

Tags: postgresql, function, dblink

All,

I'm running a query on the target server that retrieves data from a source server. My query is using the digest function. Digest is on both servers. It is embedded in a UDF that is also present on both servers.  BTW, the "select" portion of the query runs perfectly on the source server.

I would think that when you submit a remote query it will execute on the remote box.  I am receiving a "1 function digest(text, unknown) does not exist ..." error. Also, since all the functions are in the public schema on both servers, I don't see how Postgres is failing is find the function.

Any help appreciated.

TIA,

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries are executed on server specified in connection string. If no host was given, then on localhost. They are executed using role from connection string. That also includes `search_path` of that role.

Unrelated to your question, but I would try 2 things while debugging that issue you described:

1. Connect to remote server using the same role as dblink connection string and executing query
2. schema qualify that function in dblink: `public.digest(..)`

Comment: Thanks, Lukasz!   I developed the query on the remote server and it runs perfectly on that platform.  The digest function is embedded in a hierarchy of functions that create a "hash" to encrypt certain columns.  I don't have edit access to these functions, so I can't modify them as you suggest.  Isn't the "public" schema in Postgres roughly analogous to "dbo" in SQL Server?  My connection is to the schema where the data is located.  When I run the query from within this schema, it is able to find the functions, but it is not able to find them via dblink.

Comment: I got someone with the necessary permissions to alter the function to fully qualify the function call.  This appears to only be a problem with dblink.

Comment: @MikeA Yes, it is something like dbo in SQL Server and by default it is in role `search_path`, but that can be altered. I'm assuming this is the case for the role you are using in your dblink connection string.